# Easiest way to include _custom.less in adminhtml compile

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, custom-theme, less-compilation

We are in the process of building our own custom theme. We are being careful to use distinct names for all of our custom style class names.  But I noticed that when we create custom styles, they don't appear in the wysiwig when editing in the back-end.

Is there an easy way to tell the back-end to import our _custom.less from our custom theme (app/design/frontend/Magento/custom/web/css/sources/_customless) without overriding anything else in the existing backend?

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some more digging, I found a way to apply a _custom.less by dropping it in a neutral directory (lib/web/css/source) and then making a scary looking import in each place preceded by ../../../../etc
While it worked, it wasn't ideal. But worked was relative. The tiny_mce seems to load in an iframe when active that has it's own theme and styles.  There is apparently support for passing a custom_css parameter when creating it, but I don't see any immediate support for it in the sparse settings for the wysiwig in the back end.  While I might be able to find a way to override the javascript and/or the back-end options to allow for it, I'm thinking it might be easier to temporarily cut/paste the url to the compiled styles-l.css file when needed.

*just shakes head*

c'mon magento. You can't edit the custom css without a third party plugin or a full static content deploy in the backend. You can't see the css in the content editor.  I sure hope Adobe fixes some of this.